# Is it possible to show both percentage and remaining battery life on wingpanel?

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, battery

In Freya it is possible to show either remaining battery life (in hours:minutes) or percentage. How to do the same thing (show **both** percentage and remaining time) in Loki?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the battery icon and click "Show Percentage"

Comment: Yes, but what about remaining time?

Comment: Not that I know of. Likely wouldn't be very accurate even if it did. It's very hard to predict and dependent on CPU load, screen brightness changes, running apps, etc. Percentage is a much more reliable immediate snapshot of battery condition.